# combined probability of N items.

Tags: probability, statistics

I'm currently facing a situation that I need some help about. So here is the problem.

Let's say we have a question bank with N questions, where in each question has a defined probability score that tells the question's capability of segregating good/bad students out of the pool of students who took that question. Essentially this is a conditional probability in form:

$ P(Good\;Student/Question\;answered\;correctly) $

This probability has been calculated based on past data.

Now, I want to calculate the similar probability score of a question paper that has been created by selecting N questions from Question Bank. As per my understanding, this is the case of

$P(A\,and\,B\,and\,C....\,and\,N)$ wherein A is probability of question 1 answered correctly and so on. Considering questions are mutually exclusive (not sure about this though).

However, the problem with this approach is that the end probability after selecting N questions would be very small and I don't think that is the appropriate probability.

So what should be the suggested approach in this case. Please let me know in case any other detail is required to understand the question better.

Looking forward to any help and thanks in advance!

Peace.

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Please use [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference).

Comment: Have done a little formatting now.

Comment: @JoséCarlosSantos This post had so little mathematics and so much of the math is pure text anyways that I almost consider MathJax to be a hinderance ($P(some\;condition)$ looks worse than `P(some condition)` or P(some condition) in my eyes, although the last one fails to stand out as mathematics in an otherwise dense text). Of course, there are posts out there which are completely unreadable without MathJax (typically ones with a lot of algebra and arithmetic), but in my opinion, this isn't one of them.

Comment: @Arthur This was the first question posted here by Gaurav Pandey. That's why I thought I should warn him about MathJax. Of course it was not important in this particular post.

Comment: Would the probability of the paper segregating good/bad students not just be that of the question with highest probability of doing so? What are the rules for determining the segregation?

Comment: You may want to consider logistic regression, on those indicators $X_i$ which indicate whether the particular student is correct on the $i$-th question.

Comment: @strider Right now there are various factor that can be used to segregate the students as good/bad. One such factor that I'm considering right now is GPA.

To your first question, wouldn't other questions in that paper have any effect on the outcome? Means, what if a student answers all the remaining questions right but mark the question with highest probability incorrect? We can't say that, that particular student is bad. It's just a thought.

What do you say?

Comment: @BGM can you please explain it in little more detail?

Comment: I think you would have to clearly define the rules, e.g. what defines good or bad in terms of the overall paper? Do you use weightings according to complexity? Do you penalize for getting the easy ones wrong? etc etc